# How to Round to nearest integer in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rounding

Hello I'm using JavaScript connected to my html code to make a conversion calculator. What I am having problems on is how to make my result into a rounded integer. I'm new to JavaScript and have tried many attempts to make Math.round(report1) or Math.round(report2) work into my code. Maybe I have to create a separate function? I'm stumped and would appreciate any help for this.

```
//displaing reported values...for kg to pounds
var report1 = function (kilogram, pound) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        kilogram + "kg = " + pound + "lb";
};


//displaing reported values...for pounds to kilograms
var report2 = function (pound, kilogram) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        pound + "lb = " + kilogram + "kg";
};

//reading in value from lb to kg button
document.getElementById("p_to_kg").onclick = function () {
    var p = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    report2(p, p_to_kg(p));
};

//formula for pounds to kilograms
function p_to_kg(pound_weight) {
    return (pound_weight / 2.2);
}

//reading in value from kg to lb button
document.getElementById("kg_to_p").onclick = function () {
    var kg = document.getElementById("weight").value;
    report1(kg, kg_to_p(kg));
};

//formula for kilograms to pounds
function kg_to_p(kilogram_weight) {
    return (2.2 * kilogram_weight);
}
```

This is my issue:

[image: how to round this]

Comment: Can you put the output of 2 functions here.

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to call the round()?

Comment: I want to round the report1 and report2

Comment: The picture i just added shows that when you click on the button that say [lb to kg] you get 16.363636363636363kg. I would like 16.363636363636363kg to be 16 or if possible 16.4. I would like this to work when going from [kg to lb] as well.

Comment: lb and kg are weight (mass) units not temperature ;).

Comment: Thank you! I changed it. Was just concerned on getting the mechanics working and didn't realize that.

Comment: @Teal As I think your problem is with the value content type. I think what you're about is in my answer. check it.

Comment: Math.round(Number(number));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML input values types are string so to calculate rounded value of them you should convert them to number. there is many ways to convert them to number like call the `Number` with the `string` value or adding a `plus sign` (+) (or division or multiply):

```js
var val = document.querySelector('#val');
var k2l = document.querySelector('#kg-to-lb');
var l2k = document.querySelector('#lb-to-kg');
var res = document.querySelector('#result');

//displaing reported values...for kg to pounds
var report1 = function(kilogram, pound) {
  result.innerHTML =
    kilogram + "kg = " + pound + "lb";
};


//displaing reported values...for pounds to kilograms
var report2 = function(pound, kilogram) {
  result.innerHTML = pound + "lb = " + kilogram + "kg";
};

k2l.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var kilogram = val.value;
  var pound = Math.round(kilogram * 2.2);
  report1(kilogram, pound);
});
l2k.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var pound = val.value;
  var kilogram = Math.round(pound / 2.2);
  report2(pound, kilogram);
});
```

```html
value
<input id="val" type="number" />

<button id="kg-to-lb">kg 2 lb</button>
<button id="lb-to-kg">lb 2 kg</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: @Teal so what's the problem? you can use my code by just replacing element ids.

Comment: This is helpful and I'm trying to make it work for my code.

Comment: I'm sorry but what does l2k.addEventListener('click', function(e) mean and how do I change this part?

Comment: *"you should convert them to number"* - The `*` and `/` operators both convert their operands to numbers.

Comment: @Teal This is the click event listener just like your `document.getElementById("p_to_kg").onclick = function ()...`. Better use mine.

Comment: Ok thank you. Also is document.getElementById the same as document.querySelector?

Comment: @Teal `getElementById` accepts the id of element meanwhile the `querySelector` returns just one element (or null) with the given query (here `#` + id).

Comment: Okay thank you. I'm still having issues editing your code.

Comment: I tried using your code directly and it's not giving me anything when I click my buttons.

Comment: @Teal I don't know what's wrong with your implementation. if there is no problem with the `id`s then create a fiddle and add the link here.

Comment: @mortezaT shouldn't your code work if I paste it exactly in my compiler?

Comment: @Teal What do you mean by compiler?

Comment: Typo...i meant compiler

Comment: @Teal You should create an `HTML` file and then put the `html` of mine in body tag and all `JS` inside a `script` tag. that's it.

Comment: @mortezaT Found my mistake! Darn semicolon missing. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 2):

There are three methods of the **Math** object and one from **Number** you may use:

```
var f = 56.14523;

console.log('f: '+f);
console.log('Math.round: '+Math.round(f));
console.log('Math.ceil: '+Math.ceil(f));
console.log('Math.floor: '+Math.floor(f));
console.log('Number.toFixed: '+f.toFixed(2));
```

The output is:

> f: 56.14523
>
> Math.round: 56
>
> Math.ceil: 57
>
> Math.floor: 56
>
> Number.toFixed: 56.15

*Math.round* will round up to the next integer if the decimal point is **.5** or greater.

*Math.ceil* will always increase the value up to the next integer.

*Math.floor* will always decrease the value down to the next integer.

*Number.toFixed* will round to the number of decimal places passed as a parameter.

If you are getting values from inputs, you must first convert them from strings to float values with **parseFloat**.  For example:

```
function processNumber() {
    var f = document.getElementById("float-input").value;
    f = parseFloat(f);
    if (isNaN(f)) {
        console.log(f+" is not a number");
    } else {
        console.log(f+" rounded is "+Math.round(f));
    }
    return "Temperature: " + Math.round(f) + " degrees";
}

document.getElementById("output-div").textContent = processNumber();
```